# Simple socket forwarding in linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets

The scenario is pretty simple:

Using TCP/IP I have a client which connects to me (server) I want to forward the data the socket sends me to another socket which I opened and the data I received from that socket backwards.Just like a proxy.

Right now I have 1 thread one who listens from incoming connection and spawns another 2 when a connection from the client is established. I must use a mechanism for communicating in the threads.

Is there anything simpler which I can use to act as a TCP/IP proxy ? Does Linux have socket forwarding or some kind of mechanism ?

Comment: Why spawn two new threads on incoming connections? One is enough, and it can do both sending and receiving to and from both connections. Read about non-blocking sockets and the `select` system call.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by something simpler? A socket does not do anything magically on its own, you need to manually code to receive and forward traffic. There are several open source proxies available in general such as squid. But they are basically web proxies. Won't work for ANY tcp connections but rather only HTTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need threads. Take a look at `select()`, `epoll()` or `kqueue()` in order to manage multiple sockets without any thread (if you're on Windows, it's the `completion port`).

[This is an example of a select-based server](http://www.lowtek.com/sockets/select.html), it will be a good start.

Answer (score 16):

You can use iptables to do [port forwarding](http://www.fclose.com/w/Port_Forwarding_Using_iptables). It's not a c solution, but it is a [2-line](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/73) that has good performance and which will have minimal debugging.

From the second link:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth1 -p tcp \
         --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.50:80

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW \
         --dport 80 -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
```

The first line forward from port 80 to port 80 on 192.168.1.50 and the second accepts the connection, keeping iptables from dropping it.

You can add additional constraints with other iptables flags such as `-s 10.0.3.0/24` would catch all the addresses with a source of 10.0.3.0 to 10.0.3.255

Comment: Thanks but I must route the traffic based on incoming ips

Comment: you can do that with additional flags, like -s

Answer (score 12):

One user level solution is using `socat`. For example, to accept connections on port 8080 and forward them to 192.168.1.50:9090 you can use:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:8080,fork TCP:192.168.1.50:9090
```

The `fork` option makes `socat` permit multiple connections.

Comment: I must route the traffic based on incoming ips

Comment: Using the `iptables` approach you can add matching rules for the source address (`--source`). Doing this in user space would require something more advanced, like using the `squid` proxy program.

Answer (score 2):

For simple socket forwarding, let the kernel do it. Use iptables, or one of the frontends to configure it.

If you need complicated data sniffing/mangling/forwarding for real-world use, write an iptables module.

If you need to tee (duplicate/split) the data stream, or inspect or modify the data, then read on.

Linux 2.6.17 and later, with glibc 2.5 and later, do provide a couple of nice functions: [`splice()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/splice.2.html) and [`tee()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/tee.2.html). You can use these to avoid having the *payload* copied to and from userspace, telling the kernel to transfer a specific amount of bytes from one descriptor to another. (`tee()` does not consume the data, allowing you to send one or more copies of the data to other descriptors.)

You could use your two threads per connection (one per direction), and have each thread read inspect/mangle/tee the data stream as necessary. When you know you have *N* incoming bytes to forward to one outgoing socket, use `splice()`. If you have more than one outgoing socket, use nonblocking outgoing sockets, `tee()` small chunks at a time (but use `splice()` for the last outgoing socket for each chunk).

Your threads can read some/all of the incoming data to decide what to do with it, but remember that you need to `write()` or `send()` the part you already read that needs to be sent, before using `splice()` or `tee()`; they don't magically pick up already consumed data.